# How to use the options of jQuery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying use jQuery's AJAX handling [`.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) while passing several variables along with the request.

Normally, as a xmlhttp request GET, I would pass variables like so:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","myfile.php?        
var1="+data1+"&var2="+data2+"&var3="+data3+"&var4="+data4,true);
```

Using load, I can't get this to work (the request doesn't succed):

```
$('#txtHint').load("myfile.php?var1="+data1+"&var2="+data2+"&var3="+data3+"&var4="+data4 , null, function (){ });
```

In the space where it says "null" in the .load example, is the parameter for: 
"data: This optional parameter represents a map of data that is sent with the request".

If I'm unserstanding that correctly, I believe I can use it to send my variables along with the request. However, I can't find information on how to format it.

How can I pass my variables along with the request using .load?

Comment: no reason it shouldn't work as shown. What is happening in browser console with the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your method should work as a GET to `myfile.php`.

If you want to use the `data` parameter instead, then look at [the official jQuery API docs for the `.load()` method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) (not to be confused with the `.load()` event handling method), where it says:

> **data**
>   Type: [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) or [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String)
>   A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

So you can pass it as a string or as an object.

As a string (which you more or less already have):

```
$('#txtHint').load('myfile.php',
    "var1="+data1+"&var2="+data2+"&var3="+data3+"&var4="+data4,
    function() { }
);
```

As an object (*note that this makes your request a* `POST`):

```
$('#txtHint').load('myfile.php',
    {
        var1: data1,
        var2: data2,
        var3: data3,
        var4: data4
    },
    function() { }
);
```

Most of the examples in the jQuery docs don't use the `data` parameter, but the last two examples at the very bottom of the page (as of typing this answer) shows some basic examples of using it in the object format.

Comment: OP method should also work. Also have to note that if object is passed as data will make `post` request per docs

Comment: Thanks, That work great. 
And thank you charlietfl for pointing out that you retrieve the variables as POST & not GET when using .load.